# Настройка сети с VPN

Tags: linux, сеть, vpn, cisco

Есть сеть которая изображена на [картинке](http://pixs.ru/showimage/000jpg_8178599_8750382.jpg).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки сети:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1C:AF:F7:79:E2:AC
          inet addr:10.100.40.1  Bcast:10.100.40.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
          inet6 addr: fe80::1eaf:f7ff:fe79:e2ac/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6878786 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7715654 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1220308832 (1.1 GiB)  TX bytes:1024236321 (976.7 MiB)
          Interrupt:217 Base address:0xc000
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:6E:D5:19:05
          inet addr:10.100.40.253  Bcast:10.100.40.255  Mask:255.255.255.128
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:6eff:fed5:1905/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1120808 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1310253 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:446481276 (425.7 MiB)  TX bytes:147164180 (140.3 MiB)
          Interrupt:201 Base address:0x8800
eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:80:48:45:E6:61
          inet addr:192.168.253.2  Bcast:192.168.253.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
          inet6 addr: fe80::280:48ff:fe45:e661/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:854317 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:826872 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:688427557 (656.5 MiB)  TX bytes:131585058 (125.4 MiB)
          Interrupt:209
imq0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:16000  Metric:1
          RX packets:816398 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:816117 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:11000
          RX bytes:117863683 (112.4 MiB)  TX bytes:117851319 (112.3 MiB)
imq1      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:16000  Metric:1
          RX packets:1302861 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1302861 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:11000
          RX bytes:128273125 (122.3 MiB)  TX bytes:128273125 (122.3 MiB)
imq2      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:16000  Metric:1
          RX packets:844639 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:844637 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:11000
          RX bytes:671354149 (640.2 MiB)  TX bytes:671352529 (640.2 MiB)
imq3      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:16000  Metric:1
          RX packets:1073960 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1071749 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:11000
          RX bytes:425980556 (406.2 MiB)  TX bytes:424263556 (404.6 MiB)
```

При установке *VPN*-соединения из удаленного офиса с *CISCO* будет ли видна локальная сеть офиса, которая находится за свичем?

Если нет, то как это сделать?

Comment: для таких штук удобна openvpn.

Answer (score 1):

1. Нет не будет.
2. Прописать на cisco маршрут к этой сети, через proxy, разрешить forward этих пакетов на proxy. По хорошему proxy сам должен дать маршрут для сети за switch, но это уже зависит от того каким образом у вас организуется vpn.

Comment: И разрешить  ICMP на прокси.